# Firebase Facebook authentication showing weird activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

We are implementing Firebase Facebook authentication for one of our projects. We have followed the steps mentioned in the documentation as well.

Here is the oAuth URL:

```
https://<APP_NAME>.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler
```

I've added the rest of the credentials as well (i.e the `APP_ID` & `APP_SECRET`), moreover the app is in development stage and I've added the `key hash` as well to the Facebook portal and Firebase portal.

The `Login` initial flow works well, but when the user `confirm` the permission to grant access, the `callback` register doesn't respond at all, neither with `negative` nor `positive` acknowledgement.

Here's our piece of code:

```
     private static final String TAG = "FacebookLogin";

    private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

 mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
                // ...
            }
        };

        // Initialize Facebook Login button
        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.button_facebook_login);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
        loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
                handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
                // ...
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError"+ error);
                // ...
            }
        });

@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }

    private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(FacebookLoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }
```

Please let us know if we missed anything. I'm assuming there's something wrong about the `callback` URL, thus a bit more information on the same would be helpful as Firebase documentation doesn't clearly state about how to build up that URL. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add

> mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

in your onActivityResult block?

Edit

Referring to the sample from Firebase https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/minSdkJellybean/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/FacebookLoginActivity.java,

> ```
> @Override
> protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
>     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
>     mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
> }
> ```

If this is not added, there would be no callback.

Comment: we didn't, can you please brief more about this?